# JQuery - wait for nested iFrame to finish loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Today I've come across an issue which is slightly agitating me. I am writing a Chrome Extension for a specific web-based application. The webpage is a (wrapper) iframe, within the real page can be found, but within that iframes are even more iframes.

In order to identify where I currently am in the application I need to read some data, which is two iframes deep. I have found a way to get the string I am looking for with the following:

```
document.getElementById("firstiframe").contentWindow.document.getElementById("secondiframe").contentWindow.document.getElementById("theelement").innerText;
```

Here the problem is, as this gets executed all the needed frames must exist. Since the `secondiframe` is loaded after the script is executed it fails at the `getElementById("secondiframe")` for it doesn't exist yet.

It appeared to me I need to patiently wait till the second iframe is loaded until I execute the searching. Here I cannot come further than the first iframe.

```
$('#firstiframe').load(function() {
    $('#secondiframe').load(function() {
        console.log("We made it!");
    });
});
```

That didn't work, someone suggested me to look for something like this:

```
$('#firstiframe').load(function() {
    $(this).contents().find('#secondiframe').load(function() {
        console.log("We made it!");
    });
});
```

Yet that was neither a success, it never passes/matches to the secondiframe.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You said the second `iframe` does not exist, when you load the first.
The delegated handler would take care of that.

```
$('divAroundBothIframes').on('load', '#secondiframe', function() {
    console.log("We made it!");    
});
```

Or something around that line, fiddle around a bit.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: This one still doesn't work, it doesn't pass at all. Can't I make it work with something like this? `$('#firstiframe').contentWindow.document.GetElementById('secondiframe').load`

Comment: @user3249751 Hmm, what exactly do you mean with: "does not pass at all"? Check my edited answer, without a jsFiddle or something it would be cumbersome to make it happen. You can mix jQuery and vanilla Javascript, yes, but that would not cater for your problem, that the object you want to pass a handler to is not present on passing that handler, do you understand?

Answer (score 0):

In these kind of scenarios, what I do is write a function at the parent page and include onload from the iframe content. You can call the function in your parent window by using parent.functionName();

In your case, what I suggest is to keep variables to point if the iframes are loaded. Something like isIFrame1Loaded and isIFrame2Loaded. These should be updated by onLoad functions which are triggered from inside iframes. They should also check if all the variables are set and if so, execute your code.